How to convert google calendar date into a usable date? ('20240713T011500Z')
I'm getting google calendar events, via iCal, which have a date like this:
'20240713T011500Z'

The regular php funcs dont seem to like this format.
This function works, but seems pretty clunky. Is there not a built in way to deal with this format?
function convertGCalDate($gdate){
    $parts = explode('T', $gdate);
    $date  = $parts[0];
    $nums  = str_split($date);
    $date  = $nums[0].$nums[1].$nums[2].$nums[3].'-'.$nums[4].$nums[5].'-'.$nums[6].$nums[7];
    
    $time = trim($parts[1], 'Z');
    $zulu = str_ends_with($parts[1], 'Z');
    
    $nums    = str_split($time);
    $newtime = $nums[0].$nums[1].':'.$nums[2].$nums[3].':'.$nums[4].$nums[5];
    
    $dt = $date.' '.$newtime;
    
    // this is my TZ func, it works, when I finally get the dt into the right format.
    // $datetime = new DateTime($time);
    // $datetime->setTimezone($that_tz);
    // etc
    $dt = getTimeInThisTimezone($dt, $thatTZ = 'Z', $thisTZ = 'America/Los_Angeles', $outformat = null);
    
    return $dt;
    //2024-07-12 7:15 pm

}

$whatIwant =  convertGCalDate('20240713T011500Z');


You can use Date::parseFromFormat()

Did you mean DateTime::createFromFormat()?

"The regular php funcs dont seem to like this format" — I'd say they do :-? https://3v4l.org/Tntbv

I assume that input properly validated.
I think date() and strtotine() should do the trick.
function convertGCalDate($gdate){
return echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($gdate));
}


Yeah, I was missing strtotime(), thanks, friend.

Yeah, you don't need to do that. You probably also don't need to do whatever is in the getTimeInThisTimezone() function either.
var_dump(
    $d = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Ymd\THisO', '20240713T011500Z'),
    $d2 = $d->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('America/Vancouver')),
    $d2->format('Y-m-d g:i a')
);

Output:
object(DateTimeImmutable)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2024-07-13 01:15:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}

object(DateTimeImmutable)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2024-07-12 18:15:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(17) "America/Vancouver"
}

string(18) "2024-07-12 6:15 pm"

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php

Surely datetime parsing has multiple canonicals on Stack Overflow, right?

So, the createFromFormat()  is more accurate than strtotime()? Strtotime() is guessing and cFF() is more direct?

And, the O stands in for the tz? I cant find docs on this.

Yes, strtotime() is guessing at the format, and the O specifier is indeed in the docs I linked.
